# Rspec Include matcher producing incorrect results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

This seems a bit silly, but I'm just starting out with Rspec, following the [Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec/read#leanpub-auto-why-rspec) tutorial.

I have a `Review` model that has a boolean column, `recommended`:

```
Class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :recommended, :in => [true, false], message: "recommended not a boolean value"

end
```

So I wrote a basic Rspec test to make sure the user couldn't save with a nil value:

```
 it "is invalid without a non-boolean recommended value" do
    review = Review.new(recommended: nil)
    review.valid?
    expect(review.errors[:recommended]).to include("not a boolean value")
  end
```

However, Rspec is failing the test. The terminal says:

```
 1) Review is invalid without a non-boolean recommended value
     Failure/Error: expect(review.errors[:recommended]).to include("not a boolean value")
       expected ["recommended not a boolean value"] to include "not a boolean value"
     # ./spec/models/destination_review_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The second line confuses me: `expected ["recommended not a boolean value"] to include "not a boolean value"`, because the substring is contained within the error message. No other tests I've written are getting this error.

Can someone explain to me why this is failing?

Answer (score 0):

`to include` tests membership in a collection or matches substring in a string. You're trying to mix the two. i.e. `review.errors[:recommended]` returns an array and you're trying to check for a string. if you were to do `review.errors[:recommended].join` it should pass.